# Improve this clojure code: depth-first search algorithm

Tags: clojure, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

### Context

As an exercise for myself (I'm learning clojure). I wanted to implement the  `Depth-first search` algorithm.

### How I did it

Using recursion

```lisp
(def graph 
  {:s {:a 3 :d 4}
   :a {:s 3 :d 5 :b 4}
   :b {:a 4 :e 5 :c 4} 
   :c {:b 4} 
   :d {:s 4 :a 5 :e 2} 
   :e {:d 2 :b 5 :f 4} 
   :f {:e 4 :g 1}})

(def stack [[:s]])

(def goal :g)

(defn cost [Graph start goal]
  (goal (start Graph)))

(defn hasloop? [path]
  (not (= (count path) (count (set path)))))

(defn atgoal? [path]
  (= goal (last path)))

(defn solved? [stack]
  (some true? (map atgoal? stack)))

(defn addtopath [path node]
    (conj path node))

(defn pop* [stack]
    (last stack))


(defn findpath [stack]
    (if (not (solved? stack))
        (let [first* (pop* stack) l (last first*) ] 
                (findpath (drop-last 
                    (remove hasloop?  (lazy-cat
                                            (map #(addtopath first* %) 
                                            (keys (l graph))) stack)))))
        [(first stack)]))
```

How to use

(findpath stack)

### Question

I'm really really interested in how this code can be improved. Both in readability, efficiency and performance.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I will move my question to there

Answer (score 4):

Do not use lazy-cat, your seq is realized if you do `drop-last` on it.

Recursion in Clojure should be done using `loop`/`recur` to avoid stack overflows.

Do not put several `let`s on a  single line:

```
(let [first* (pop* stack)
      l      (last first*)]
```

Use `(if-not` instead of `(if (not`. Same for `(not=`

Use lower-case var names (`graph`, not `Graph`). Keep capitalization to classes, records and protocols.